# Grails - Externalized Configuration Restart

Tags: grails, configuration

If I externalize part of my Grails configuration, must I restart my container for the change to be found? Is there any workaround to this if so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no automatic watch for changes to external config files. There's a good solution here that involves making a controller request to trigger a reload: http://jetlet.blogspot.com/2011/02/reload-external-config-file-dynamically.html

There's also this plugin, which looks like it hasn't been updated in a long time and may not work: http://www.grails.org/plugin/reloadable-config

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in late here, but there's also

http://www.grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload